# how can i find all files with same extension within directory using C language?

Tags: c

how can i find all files with same extension within directory using C language ??
 i mean i want to enter the extension only as an argument then i want to list all the file with the extension i was entered

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dent;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: ./Exe_Name dir_name file_name");    
    }
    dir = opendir(argv[1]);
    //this part 
    if(dir!=NULL) { 
        while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
           if(strcmp(dent->d_name,argv[2])==0)
               printf("%s\n",dent->d_name);

    } else
        printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    closedir(dir);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted on askubuntu and moftalk, presumably to waste as much contributors' time as possible and get the best spread of copypasta homework answers.

Comment: So your actual problem is comparing two strings `"filename.xyz"` (from `argv`) and `"otherfilename.xyz"` (from `readdir()` or `scandir()`) and return true when the extensions match? Of which there is no effort in your code ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of abusive and selfish cross-posting.

Comment: There is no way to do this just with standard C. Which system are you using? Please edit your post and add the relevant tags, ie Linux, POSIX etc.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `scandir`.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir):

> ```
>    int scandir(const char *dir, struct dirent ***namelist,
>           int(*filter)(const struct dirent *),
>           int(*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
>
>    int alphasort(const void *a, const void *b);
>    int versionsort(const void *a, const void *b);
> ```
>
> The scandir() function scans the directory  dir,  calling  filter()
>   on    each  directory entry.  Entries for which filter() returns
>   non-zero are    stored in strings allocated via malloc(), sorted using
>   qsort() with the    comparison  function compar(), and collected in
>   array namelist which is    allocated via malloc().  If filter is NULL,
>   all entries are selected.
>
> The alphasort() and versionsort() functions can be used as the
>   comparison  function  compar().  The former sorts directory entries
>   using strcoll(3), the latter using strverscmp(3) on the strings
>   (*a)->d_name and    (*b)->d_name.

Comment: `scandir`'s POSIX-2008, newer than I was aware. This saves a huge amount of time over a manual parsing of sequential `readdir` (POSIX.1-2001) results as I was about to propose. Points to you!

Comment: Nice.  Just remember that `versionsort()` is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 1):

The old school method would be to use `glob`,  as in `man -S 3 glob`

```
   #include <glob.h>

   int glob(const char *pattern, int flags,
            int (*errfunc) (const char *epath, int eerrno),
            glob_t *pglob);
   void globfree(glob_t *pglob);
```